# Diffrent facebook comment box for each title on same page

Tags: php, html, facebook

I tried a lot , and one of my tried script is dynamically creating link .

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="url?link=<?php echo $row[id]?>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="15" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

the page demo page structure is in below link .

[image].

but neither i can see comment and using another link shows same comments on all the posts .

hope i'm making clear and thanks for your help in advance .

Comment: 1. `data-href` should contain an absolute URL. 2. You need to make sure that the Open Graph `og:url` meta tag (if exists) points to the same URL as given in `data-href`. (Go check your implementation using Facebook’s debug tool if unsure.)

Comment: Yes i'm using absolute URL , it just give a reference , how i'm using . Concern i using multiple comment box on same page . i want different facebook comment box on same page . with different comments that are posted for different titles .

Answer (score 0):

i found how to resolve it , in stackoverflow

just it was url what was need to be changed .

http://www.example.com/page.php/54/

this is what was needed .

Thanks